# i try to write login page in Osgi-karaf with ldap but i got this error "Can't connect to the LDAP server: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]"

Tags: authentication, ldap, osgi, karaf

i want to write login page in Osgi-karaf.

My login.xhtml is ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World_denememememe</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - login.xhtml</h3>
    <h:form id="formLogin" prependId="false"
            onsubmit="document.getElementById('formLogin').action = 'j_security_check';">
      <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <f:facet name="header">
          Login
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username: "/>
        <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" value="#{helloBean.name}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password: "/>
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" value="#{helloBean.pass}" />

        <f:facet name="footer">
          <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{helloBean.birlestir}"/>
        </f:facet>
      </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and my web.xml is ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>xhtmlDeneme</display-name>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>karaf</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

I'm using karaf. I know when karaf is seen "j_security_check", it look "ldap-module.xml". And here is my ldap-module.xml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

  <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="1">
    <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule"
                 flags="required">
        initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
      connection.username=--valid username--
      connection.password=--valid password--
      connection.protocol=
      connection.url=--valid url--
      user.base.dn=cn=Users,dc=vmldapdevelop,dc=com
      user.filter=(cn=%u)
      user.search.subtree=true
      role.base.dn=cn=Groups,dc=vmldapdevelop,dc=com
      role.name.attribute=cn
      role.filter=(uniquemember=%nsdn)
      role.search.subtree=true
      authentication=simple
    </jaas:module>
  </jaas:config>
</blueprint>
```

I try everything almost, but i don't change this error! When i delete from login.xhtml "j_security_check" part, its working.

Anybody help me?